# C# WordprocessingDocument - insert an image in a cell

Tags: c#, image, openxml, wordprocessingml

I have a method that replaces the tags in the document specific text. How do I replace the label picture?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by label picture? Explain your question in detail so that others can help you.

Comment: PersonMainPhoto, PersonPhoto2, PersonPhoto3 - labels, it must be replaced pictures

Comment: This link might be useful - http://alemiralles.blogspot.nl/2013/08/how-to-replace-text-with-images-on-word.html

Comment: I use Open XML SDK

Answer (score 10):

Here is a piece of code that looks for a cell with the text 'PersonMainPhoto' inside a table. The tabel-cell is cleared, and an image is inserted. Hopefully this can guide you in the right direction.

Inserting an image is a two part process:

- Add image part to the document
- Insert a reference to the image inside    the body text - with all kinds of details regarding scaling,    positioning etc.

The code for inserting the reference is taken from the brilliant OpenXML SDK documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430.aspx

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using A = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using DW = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing;
using PIC = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;

namespace StackOverflow
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string file = @"c:\temp\mydoc.docx";
      string imageFile = @"c:\temp\myimage.jpg";
      string labelText = "PersonMainPhoto";

      using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file, isEditable: true))
      {
        var mainPart = document.MainDocumentPart;
        var table = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Table>().First();

        var pictureCell = table.Descendants<TableCell>().First(c => c.InnerText == labelText);

        ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
          imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        pictureCell.RemoveAllChildren();
        AddImageToCell(pictureCell, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));

        mainPart.Document.Save();
      }
    }

    private static void AddImageToCell(TableCell cell, string relationshipId)
    {
      var element =
        new Drawing(
          new DW.Inline(
            new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
            new DW.EffectExtent()
            {
              LeftEdge = 0L,
              TopEdge = 0L,
              RightEdge = 0L,
              BottomEdge = 0L
            },
            new DW.DocProperties()
            {
              Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
              Name = "Picture 1"
            },
            new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
            new A.Graphic(
              new A.GraphicData(
                new PIC.Picture(
                  new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                    new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                    {
                      Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                      Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"
                    },
                    new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                  new PIC.BlipFill(
                    new A.Blip(
                      new A.BlipExtensionList(
                        new A.BlipExtension()
                        {
                          Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                        })
                     )
                    {
                      Embed = relationshipId,
                      CompressionState =
                        A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                    },
                    new A.Stretch(
                      new A.FillRectangle())),
                    new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                      new A.Transform2D(
                        new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                        new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                      new A.PresetGeometry(
                        new A.AdjustValueList()
                      )
                      { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
              )
              { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
          )
          {
            DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
            DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U
          });

      cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: brilliant? with all that hardcoded stuff like `{ Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }` any idea is and `Name = "New Bitmap Image.jpg"`? and what is `Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"`?

Answer (score 0):

how do the picture fit, just into tablecell!??

not to fix it .
Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L

like this?

```
   TableCellProperties tableCellProperties1 = VARIABLE.GetFirstChild<TableCellProperties>();

   TableCellWidth tableCellWidth1 = tableCellProperties1.GetFirstChild<TableCellWidth>();

   int _width = Int32.Parse(tableCellWidth1.Width);

   TableRowProperties tableRowProperties1 = 

   VARIABLE.Parent.GetFirstChild<TableRowProperties>();

   TableRowHeight tableRowHeight1 = 

   tableRowProperties1.GetFirstChild<TableRowHeight>();
   int _height = Int32.Parse(tableRowHeight1.Val);     

   document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
```