# Add image to a word page using memory stream

Tags: c#, openxml

I am trying to use the memory stream to add an image to a word document. If I get the page from a file everithing works correctly(the commented code). How can I add the same image from the Byte array. I added AddImageToCell( I borrowed the method from the net).

[C# WordprocessingDocument - insert an image in a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877119/c-sharp-wordprocessingdocument-insert-an-image-in-a-cell)

```
//string imageFile = @"C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\test.png";
//ImagePart imagePart = document.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
//using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(imageFile, FileMode.Open))
//{
//     imagePart.FeedData(stream);
//}
//AddImageToCell(tc3, document.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));

byte[] signatureTempl = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\test.png");
ImagePart imagePart = document.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);


using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
       using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap())
       {
         bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
              ms.Position = 0;
              imagePart.FeedData(ms);
       }

       AddImageToCell(tc3, document.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));

}
```

Comment: Please provide the _minimum reproducible source_. In your case, it includes the implementation of `AddImageToCell`. Can you edit your question and add it? And what type is your variable `document`?

Comment: I am confused. You are creating a new (empty) Bitmap object and just dump that into your MemoryStream while not using the byte array anywhere at all. Why did you do that? Also, you are reading a _PNG_ image (according to the file extension), but your code instructs the document to add a _JPG_ image part. Does that look right to you?

Comment: Because I couldn't figure out how to use it in my scenatiro. I added a link to the 'AddImageToCell' method